# otice: Undefined variable: row in ...uredi.php on line 19 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know what I am doing wrong...

My code is:

```
<?php 

    if ( isset($_GET['uredi'])) {
        $id = $_GET['uredi'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM changelog");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    }

 ?>
    <div class="container main">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="page-header">
              <h1>Changelog <small><a href="dodaj" title="dodaj"><div class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Dodaj</div></a></small></h1>
            </div>
            <form role="form" action="includes/dodaj-changelog.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <textarea name="vsebina"><?php echo $row['vsebina']; ?></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 20px" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj</button>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

And it always give me error: Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\ocene\uredi.php on line 19 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0000142728{main}( )..\uredi.php:0 ">

But $row is defined...

Comment: is `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)` line 19?

Comment: Line 19: <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

Comment: `$row` is only set if `isset($_GET['uredi'])` is true. But you're using the variable whether it's set or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're only defining `$row` **if $_GET['uredi'] isset** - in this case, change line 19 to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo (isset($row['id'])) ? $row['id'] : ''; ?>">
```

...and the same for your other variables. If you want a default value for your fields, put them in the `''` section of that code.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out, you're only defining `$row` inside of the if block, which will only be executed if you access '`uredi.php?uredi=SOMETHING`' or pass uredi as a GET parameter in some other way.

Why do you need the if block, and what does the uredi parameter represent?

Answer (score 0):

What if you change:
    `<form ... action="includes/dodaj-changelog.php" ... >`

to 
    `<form ... action="includes/dodaj-changelog.php?uredi=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" ... >` and the rest stays the same.

When you submit your form, somehow it "forgets" which row in your sql table it is working on, that data you got when using `$_GET['uredi'];` this way I'm assuring to get uredi again (the id - unique value in your table that identifies the specific row you need) and keep it while executing the SELECT.

Give it a try. It worked for me for an UPDATE query scenario.